# Concatenation in JPA 1.0

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa

I am facing an issue while trying to concatenate column values in JPA 1.0 named query :

```
SELECT aum.id.pin, aum.id.planNBR, aum.id.subPlanNBR, AVG(aum.aumAmount)
FROM AUMBalanceDO aum 
WHERE " + "CONCAT(aum.id.pin,aum.id.planNBR,aum.id.subPlanNBR) NOT IN (

    SELECT CONCAT(PAP.pin,edo.planNBR,edo.subPlanNBR) 
    FROM " + "ParticipantAdvicePortfolioDO PAP, EnrollmentDO edo 
    WHERE PAP.userID = edo.userID AND edo.status ='E' 
    AND edo.startDT < :endDate " + "
    AND (edo.endDT > :endDate OR edo.endDT IS NULL)

) 
AND aum.id.priceDate 
BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate GROUP BY aum.id.pin, " + "aum.id.planNBR, aum.id.subPlanNBR"
```

I am getting the below exception while trying to run the query,

```
unexpected token [concat]
```

As per the error its clear that in JPA 1.0 we dont have concat function is there any other alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add your code please?

Comment: My named query,                                               SELECT aum.id.pin, aum.id.planNBR, aum.id.subPlanNBR, AVG(aum.aumAmount) FROM AUMBalanceDO aum WHERE " +
    "CONCAT(aum.id.pin,aum.id.planNBR,aum.id.subPlanNBR) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(PAP.pin,edo.planNBR,edo.subPlanNBR) FROM " +
    "ParticipantAdvicePortfolioDO PAP, EnrollmentDO edo WHERE PAP.userID = edo.userID AND edo.status ='E' AND edo.startDT < :endDate " +
    "AND (edo.endDT > :endDate OR edo.endDT IS NULL)) AND aum.id.priceDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate GROUP BY aum.id.pin, " +
    "aum.id.planNBR, aum.id.subPlanNBR"

Comment: Can't you use a not Exists subquery instead where you pass in the aum.id.pin,aum.id.planNBR,aum.id.subPlanNBR values to use within the subquery.  Something like where not exists (PAP 
    FROM " + "ParticipantAdvicePortfolioDO PAP, EnrollmentDO edo 
    WHERE PAP.userID = edo.userID AND edo.status ='E' 
    AND edo.startDT < :endDate " + "
    AND (edo.endDT > :endDate OR edo.endDT IS NULL) and aum.id.pin =PAP.pin and aum.id.planNBR = edo.planNBR and aum.id.subPlanNBR = edo.subPlanNBR)

Comment: Thanks Chris for your suggestion. I am not able to do that because i need to get the records (pin, plan and sub plan) from AUMBalanceDO which are not available in given sub query.

Answer (score 0):

Plain SQL Native concatenation '||' seems to be working just fine in JPQL of JPA 1.0 spec (JPA is provided here by Hibernate 3.3.x and RDBMS is Oracle 11).

```
SELECT NEW PartSearchView(partIssue.id, partIssue.stage || partIssue.issue) 
                FROM PartIssue partIssue INNER JOIN partIssue.part part
```

The signature of constructor used above is:

```
PartSearchView(Long id, String stageIssue)
```

I got a nice concatenation of both stage and issue fed into PartSearchView constructor.

Hope this helps!

Cheers!